# SQL comparing Null date with another date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have this code and I would like to understand why it prints 'Equal' when comparing a null date with a non null date.

What should I do if I want to make an update and this happens?

```
Declare @OldDate date               
Declare @NewDate date = '05/02/1960'        

if(@OldDate <> @NewDate)
    Print 'Different'
else
    Print 'Equal'
```

Regards, Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL`.  In most contexts, `NULL` is treated as false.  Hence, you get non-equal.

You don't specify your database.  The standard supports `NULL`-safe comparisons:

```
@oldDate is distinct from @newDate
```

Not all databases support this syntax, so you need to be more explicit;

```
@oldDate <> @newDate or
@oldDate is null and @newDate is not null or
@oldDate is not null and @newDate is null
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. I created an INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER and I am comparing the values from deleted table and inserted table to make the updates when the values are different.